Using Include on a sql view with a different db collation
I got a model and a Sql View (from another DB with another Collation setting).
I put a navigation property on my model and i want to include data from the view but it causes an error.
View defined and mapped to my class in ApplicationDbContext
 builder.Entity<VariantView>().
     ToView("VariantsView")
     .HasKey(v => v.ItemNo);

On my EF core entity
[ForeignKey("ItemNo")]
public VariantView? VariantView { get; set;}

In my query i do like
var q = dbContext.Masters.
  .Include(variant => variant!.VariantView)
  .Where(m => m.Id == request.Id);

in pure sql it is easy to fix by forcing the collation on the
..
FROM Masters m
LEFT JOIN VariantsView AS vv
     ON vv.ItemNo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = m.ItemNo COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS 
..

Is there no way to add this to the EF Include method ?
Note: I got 6 others navigation props that gets included as well so rather not go all in on SQL

it causes an error -- Please elaborate.

Use Query tags + Interceptors

My solution is to add collate statement in the SQL view
So starting with
select 
    item.[No_] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as ItemNo, 
.... 

